# Plotting images but holding visualization until instruction in R

Tags: r, plot, jpeg, visualize

I want to load two jpeg images in R consecutively but they are quite large (4000X3000 pixels)

So simply doing

```
library(biOps)
x <- readJpeg("image.jpg")
plot(x)
```

Takes a while. When the first image is displayed the user would have to fill in some observations on the image. I wanted to know if it was possible to plot the image but pause the actual visualization so as to take advantage of the time the user is filling in the data I mentioned only to display the image later, maybe upon an instruction of the user like pressing the enter key.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "fill observations on the image"? Does the user will change the image?

Comment: is hiding the window not an option?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `animation` package. `saveHTML`  will create a html file animated by SciAnimator library. You can show the first plot and stop the visualisation, go to the next, use a timer,...

```
ll.imgs <- list.files(Imgs_folder,patt='jpg',full=TRUE)
saveHTML({
  for(i in  seq_along(ll.imgs)){
    x <- readJpeg("image.jpg")
    plot(x) ##maybe you should try grid.raster(x) from grid package
  }
}, img.name = "plots", imgdir = "plots_dir", 
         htmlfile = "random.html", autobrowse = FALSE, 
         title = "Plotting images but holding visualization until instruction",
         outdir=getwd())
```